# How to download a csv from a query but keeping the original encoding in pgadmin

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I am Brazilian and I am workin with files that are encoded in windows 1252, when I execut the queries the names are fine, but when I try to export the data to excel using the download CSV I am faceing a encoding problem and all the letters with accents are having problems
I want to know how to change the encoding or the collate in the download as cvs for queries so that it have the same encoding in impoted

The code I used to import the that is

```
COPY base_ans_02 FROM 'C:\Users\ben201907_SP.csv' DELIMITER ',' 
CSV HEADER encoding 'windows-1252';
```

and one example of erro is

```
AMIL ASSISTÃŠNCIA MÃ‰DICA INTERNACIONAL S.A.
```

Comment: have you had any luck with the encoding?

Answer (score 0):

If you inserted the data in your table using the `WIN1252` encoding and it is not the default of your client, you might wanna also make sure it knows which encoding it's going to deal with.

Just set the client encoding right before your `COPY` command and you should be fine

```
SET CLIENT_ENCODING=WIN1252; 
COPY base_ans_02 TO 'path_to_file' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```